# What's the HTML entitity for a location symbol

Tags: html, css, html-entities

I'm designing a website, and require a location symbol, like the on on Twitter.

[image]

If it ends up with me having to use an image, I'm okay with that; however, it is easier for me to manipulate as an HTML entity.

The way I'd like to use it is `<h3>{entity code/image} Scotland</h3>`

Comment: Use [fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) - [here's the symbol](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/map-marker/), and [here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/7jLdv312/).

Comment: use fontawesome or Twitter bootstrp

Answer (score 8):

create your own icon using `pseudo` elements

```css
h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
h3:after {
  content: '';
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0%;
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
}
h3:before {
  content: '';
  background: white;
  width: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 8px;
  left: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 33px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<h3> Scotland</h3>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly different take on the "roll your own via pseudo-element" method.

```css
.icon {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.icon::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 1px 0 0 -6px;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid red;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<h3><i class='icon'></i> Scotland</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Include this in your `<head>` section

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And then

```
<h3><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Scotland</h3>
```

You can style it according to your need

Answer (score 1):

There is no HTML entity and no HTML character reference either for the symbol shown, since it is not an encoded character at all. Twitter uses a privately encoded font and a font trick that relies on the use of that particular font.

To use symbol in front of a heading element content, you can use the symbol as an image and make it a non-repearing background image of the element, with suitable left padding set on the element.